# Create table without creating new collection in MongoDB, NestJs

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, nestjs

I struggle with the problem. In my app, I have to create an order with several attributes and one of them is an array of ordered products. In the orderedProduct array, each object should have productId and the amount.

But, I don't want to create a new collection called OrderedProduct. In the current solution, it is creating both: empty orderedproduct and orders. And I have an issue

```
"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{\n  productId: { _id: '0a8b51d0-5bb1-4ab6-83d0-5b0c15f44e2b' },\n  amount: 3\n}\" (type Object) at path \"_id\" for model \"OrderedProduct\""
```

Schemas

```
@Schema()
export class Order {
  @Prop()
  _id: string

  @Prop({ type: Date, default: Date.now })
  confirmedDate: Date

  @Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: OrderStatus.name })
  orderStatus: OrderStatus

  @Prop()
  userName: string

  @Prop()
  email: string

  @Prop()
  phoneNumber: string

  @Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: OrderedProduct.name })
  orderedProductArray: [OrderedProduct]
}

@Schema()
export class OrderedProduct {
  @Prop(() => Int)
  amount: string

  @Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: Cloth.name })
  product: Cloth
}
```

I have not been able to do this. I will be appreciated for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the schema of your sub object. something like:

```
@Schema()
export class OrderedProduct {
  @Prop(() => Int)
  amount: string

  @Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: Cloth.name })
  product: Cloth
}
export const OrderedProductSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(OrderedProduct);


@Schema()
export class Order {
  @Prop()
  _id: string

  @Prop({ type: Date, default: Date.now })
  confirmedDate: Date

  @Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: OrderStatus.name })
  orderStatus: OrderStatus

  @Prop()
  userName: string

  @Prop()
  email: string

  @Prop()
  phoneNumber: string

  @Prop({ type: [OrderedProductSchema] })
  orderedProductArray: [OrderedProduct]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However for some reason In the database, the amount is added, but there isn't any product.

Comment: I found the reason, I have names diffrent in input props. But besides this thank you for your answer.